# In MLP, to calculate the delta, do I need to calculate the derivative of the cost function? Or can I just use the cost function result?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, derivative

In Multi Layer Perceptron networks, I have a question: in **the formula to calculate the error in the output layer**, Some articles say it is like this `"deltaOutput = (predict - expected) * derivativeOutput"`.  More in other sources, I saw that they seemed to calculate the derivative of the cost function, they calculated derivative it in Wolfram, and the formula to calculate the error was become `"derivativeError * derivativeOutput"`. **But then I got confused, and had this question: do we need to calculate the derivative of the error(the cost function) to use in the formula to calculate the delta?  Or are there cases where I can simply use `"deltaOutput = (predict - expected) * derivativeOutput"` in the formula without having to calculate the derivative of the error?**  Please, could you help me understand?

In MLP, In formula **to calculating the delta, do I need to calculate the derivative of the cost function(As in the case of the function MSE) ? Or can I just use the cost function result, And the formula for calculating the error in the output layer would just be `"(predict - expected) * derivativeOutput"?`**